# NLP, Recatungular or Polar? Sine or No Sine?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling

Let's say we have the following complex number, $V$:

$V=V_i+jV_j=V_m\angle{V_a}$

Which type of representation is better in an NLP (polar or rectangular)?

The **polar** form leads to one nasty constraint and two linear constraints:

$(\alpha V_{m,1}^2 +  \beta V_{m,1}V_{m,2}\cos{(V_{a,1}-V_{a,2})}) = X$

$V_{m,1}<=V_{max}$

$V_{m,2}<=V_{max}$

The **rectangular** form leads to three second order constraints:

$(\alpha' V_{i,1}^2 + \beta' V_{i,1}^2 + \gamma' V_{i,1}V_{j,2} + \lambda' V_{j,1}V_{i,2}) = X$

$V_{i,1}^2+V_{j,1}^2 \leq V_{max}^2$

$V_{i,2}^2+V_{j,2}^2 \leq V_{max}^2$

I asked some mathematicians in a conference and the said that it depends but in most cases the rectangular form is preferred because of avoiding the sinoidal term. What is so bad about the Sinosoidal terms that avoiding them is preferred> even though it might lead to more nonlinear constraints!

Comment: They were right: it depends.

Comment: Could you please explain more

Comment: It depends on the particular problem at hand, I can't say it differently. Who's better, Laurel or Hardy ?